# Connecting Playback Audio Source to S16 connected to X32

Tags: audio-interfaces, behringer

I am trying to run audio from my ipad via multitrack usb through the s16 which is connected to my x32. is this possible?

I can currently connect via usb my ipad directly to the x32, but the problem is I need the ipad on stage to control playback. So I'm trying to use the s16 as sort of a network to the x32 to still get the same connection.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

No, that won't work. There's a USB port on the S16 but according to the manual, it's for firmware updates only.

A long USB cable might be possible, but you'd have to test that. For cable lengths over 5 m you need a USB amplifier. I'm using two of those at home for a 12 m long link between a USB device and a computer, but that's a low-bandwidth USB 1 device. IDK if that sort of link works at the speed you need.